# Angular 4 - (onclick) pass parameter to a service

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular 4 and I was wondering how to pass a parameter value to a Service.

For example:

```
<button (onClick)="doSomething('myParameter')">Send this to Service</button>
```

Then the service would get it.

I currently have this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {

  constructor() { }

  message() {
    return 'This data goes to the component';
  }

}
```

and then get is like this:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
     console.log(this.messageService.message);
  }

}
```

but this only sends data to the component.

How do I do this?

Comment: You want to pass 'myParameter' to a method on your MessageService? What do you mean 'but this only sends data to the component.'?

Comment: You basicallyy have the idea. Just create a function in your component called doSomething. This function will then call the service method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template should talk to your component class and your component class should talk to your service.

I see you have a `doSomething` method in your template that is not defined in your component?

You need something like this:

**Component 1**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  doSomething(message: string): void {
      this.messageService.message = message;
  }

}
```

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
  message: string;

  constructor() { }

}
```

**Component 2**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  get message(): string {
     return this.messageService.message;
  }

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Comment: Basically I'll trying to use a service where i can pass a parameter from component 1 ...through the service into component 2...is this the way?

Comment: Yes. I have a working example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/KT4JLmpcwGBM2xdZQeI9?p=preview  And a blog post about it here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

Comment: Best way would be to use and Obserable in your service and have both components subscribe to the Obserable.  If you look up on the angular docs, component interaction with a service, it should show you and example of this

Comment: You don't need an Observable here. It just overly complicates the code. A simple getter is all you need.